# RangeError: “port” argument must be >= 0 and < 65536

Tags: node.js, express, router

Guys.
I'm a super newbie to NODEJS.

I just used example uploaded on github.
But the version of express is not matched with my computer setting.
So it doesn't work it is just simple example though.

error msggg

```
RangeError: "port" argument must be >= 0 and < 65536
    at assertPort (internal/net.js:17:11)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1383:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\nodeworkspace\program\app.js:90:37)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

I just figured out this problem is provoked because of nodejs new version.

but I can't find how can i resolve this code appropriate to Nodejs 4.13 version.

Please let me know how to fix it.

And this is the code letting make error above.

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Server is started. port : ' + app.get('port'));
    database.init(app, config);

});
```

Comment: Well, what's the value of `app.get('port')`? That should be the first part of your diagnosis...

Comment: @JonSkeet Server port is obviously '3000'. I just use default port value provided from Express.

Comment: No, that's not "obvious" at all. Have you actually validated that that's the case? If you write `console.log('Starting server on port ' + app.get('port'));` on the line before the code you've shown, does it actually show 3000, or are you just assuming that?

Comment: in programming the term 'obvious' many times makes the problem unnoticed... and many times that obivious is cought as the actual issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet Dammn, log said 'starting server on portundefined' That's why i a newbie haha. Then, I'm going to set the port on programm

Comment: @SanjeevPrasadThakur Righhhht. I learned one more thing in this post.

Comment: That's why i convinced the port is '3000' is app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000); is included in bin/www file. But i wrote down the line in app.js. I think it doesn't export info on www.file to app.js